# Can't send data via xmlhttp

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I could use xmlhttp and asptear or any other components to post data to external sites on WINDOWS 2003(iis 6).

not i am using 2008 server(iis 7) and i can't get worked that components to send data.

could you please guide me ?

(PS. components are tearing the pages but don't send post data, seems like tear as GET method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to post from a server-side language running on IIS? ASPTear  is for classic ASP so assuming that:

ASPTear [supports POST](http://www.alphasierrapapa.com/IisDev/Components/AspTear/), it just defaults to GET.

You could also use "`Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP`" ([example](http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art34047.asp)).